# Sumar horas en vb?

Tags: vb.net

Tengo un `DatagridView`con horas de la forma `hh:mm:ss`como podría sumar todas esas horas. Tengo lo siguiente pero no me funciona suma la hora como un string. Por ejemplo, 9:22:347:24:14

```
Dim horasT
For Each row In Datos.Rows
   If row.Cells(6).Value.ToString() <> "0" Then
      horasT += CDate(row.Cells(6).Value), "hh:mm:ss")
   End If
Next
```

Comment: Tu código está incompleto `CDate(row.Cells(6).Value), "hh:mm:ss")`, la forma como lo expones deberías tener un error de compilación. Asimismo, dices de la forma "hh:mm:ss", pero en tu ejemplo `9:22:347:24:14` no tiene ese formato.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encontré [esto](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/es-ES/0e6ec26b-74bd-4ab0-9917-aa41d2f9a71c/vbnet-sumar-horas-de-un-datagridview?forum=vbes) que tal vez te pueda servir:

```
 Dim Horas As Integer = 0
    Dim Minutos As Integer = 0

    For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows
        If Not row.IsNewRow Then
            Horas = Horas + Convert.ToDateTime(row.Cells("HORAS").Value).Hour
            Minutos = Minutos + Convert.ToDateTime(row.Cells("HORAS").Value).Minute
        End If
    Next

    txtResultado.Text = String.Format("{0}:{1}", Horas + Fix(Minutos / 60), Minutos Mod 60)
```

Comment: Hola Maria, recuerda que puedes [editar tu pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/64207/edit) e incluir la parte del código para un mejor entendimiento.

Comment: Gracias Davilo por el comentario. Ya está hecho :)

Answer (score 1):

Buenas..

Tenes un par de problemas con el código. No estas definiendo el tipo de dato de horasT, por lo tanto el compilador lo infiere, y por lo que estas diciendo lo infiere como texto (no sabría porque).

Ademas, estas usando la vieja función CDate, en lugar de utilizar un objeto datetime o timespan, o el que gustes para manejar esto.

Esos Objetos tienen un método add, que sirve para sumar otro objeto del mismo tipo a ellos.

Fijate cual es el que mas te conviene segun tu caso.

Comment: Lo que necesito es que me de un total de horas.

Answer (score 0):

Alcides Salazar.
Debido a que únicamente quieres sumar el tiempo, y tu columna en tu `DataGridView` donde está el tiempo con formato hh:mm:ss, lo he solucionado con el siguiente código que te muestro a continuación:

```
Dim horasTotal As TimeSpan
For Each registro As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows
    horasTotal += TimeSpan.Parse(registro.Cells("txtFecha").Value)
Next

Label1.Text = horasTotal.ToString
```

La parte clave del código es en guardar y sumar el tiempo como `TimeSpan` y no en `Date`.

- Me he tomado la libertad de hacer un video en YouTube mostrando esta solución
  recreando tu ejemplo, el cual puedes ver en este [enlace](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iE_UpQAkN4U&feature=youtu.be)